# "No module named memcache" using GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I updated my app using **command appcfg.py update APPNAME**.

After the update I checked and found out that my app had crashed due to following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 266, in Handle
result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 219, in __call__
self.load_middleware()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))

ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware django.contrib.sessions.middleware: "No module named memcache"
```

Can someone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: You don't see the problem on your dev server?

Comment: I have deployed it on my local machine and it works fine. But when I update on GAE, above error occurs.